# Rails 4 in a subdirectory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, deployment, routes, subdirectory

I have a dream, that one day, my Rails 4 app can be served from `/sub` in production.

Requests for `/sub` and `/sub/projects` would simply look like `/` and `/projects` to the app. All assets would be served from `/sub/assets`.

But still, in development environment, everything can be run from the root of `localhost:3000`.

Regardless of the server behind (apache / nginx), how do I need to configure the rails app?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct:

You can place project on production server everywhere you want. You just need describe it in apache or nginx config file. For apache use [DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#documentroot) directive. For nginx use [server -> root](https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/nginx/basic-nginx-configuration#server-virtual-domains-configuration) syntax.

Comment: I'm rather looking for a guide on how to use config settings like `relative_url_root`, `RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT`, `scope` in `routes.rb` in this case. How to compile assets (`config.assets.prefix = "..."`) and so on. I wish there was some common way to do it.